# jquery validation on a single ASP textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a number of textboxes on my Default.aspx page similar to what's below.

`<asp:TextBox ID="myTextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

When the user clicks the button to submit, the following javascript is executed:

```
            $(function () {
            $('#<%= myButton.ClientID %>').click(function (clickToExecuteMyMethod) {
                var userWantsToSubmit = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to press the button?");
                if (userWantsToSubmit) {
                    $.blockUI({ overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#00f' }, message: '<h1>Please wait a while...</h1>' });
                }
                if (!userWantsToSubmit) {
                    clickToExecuteMyMethod.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });
```

But I additionally want to use jquery to validate that something (anything) has been typed into myTextbox once that same button is pressed. If it validates successfully, then I want the other javascript to fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the simple case of checking an individual textbox just get the value of the textbox with `.val()`

```
$('#<%= myButton.ClientID %>').click(function (clickToExecuteMyMethod) {
    var userWantsToSubmit = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to press the button?");

    // Check to see if the textbox is empty
    var isValid = $('#<%= myTextbox.ClientID %>').val() != "";

    if (userWantsToSubmit && isValid) {
        $.blockUI({ overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#00f' }, message: '<h1>Please wait a while...</h1>' });
    } else {
        clickToExecuteMyMethod.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This isn't going to be a very scalable solution though. I would recommend that you have a look at something like the [jquery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), or try googling for other validation solutions, there are plenty around.

Comment: I will try to implement the jquery validation plugin. I was able to get this code to work, for now though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using any ASP.Net Page Validation Controls, you can just call the client-side validation routines:

```
$(function () {
    $('#<%= myButton.ClientID %>').click(function (clickToExecuteMyMethod) {
        var userWantsToSubmit = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to press the button?");
        Page_ClientValidate('validationGroup'); //validate using ASP.Net validator controls.
        if (userWantsToSubmit && Page_IsValid) {
            $.blockUI({
                "overlayCSS": {
                    "backgroundColor": "#00f"
                },
                "message": "<h1>Please wait a while...</h1>"
            });
        }
        if (!userWantsToSubmit || !Page_IsValid) {
            clickToExecuteMyMethod.preventDefault();
        }
        return Page_IsValid;
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't have any asp.net page validation controls yet, but will consider adding them.